# Biztalk mapping explicit values to looping node

Tags: mapping, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2009, biztalk-mapper

I am new to Biztalk and having some trobles with mapping:
In the destination schema i have `Attributes` node which can contain multiple `EntityMemberAttribute` child nodes (picture below). What i am trying to achieve is to get two `EntityMemberAttribute` nodes, one of which will contain child nodes with values from the source schema, and another one will contain child nodes with values, specified explicitly.

[image]

I am having troubles with that explicit values. For example i want to have the output like this:

```
<a:Attributes>
        <!-- This ones came from source XML -->
        <a:EntityMemberAttribute>
          <a:AttributeName>Address</a:AttributeName>
          <a:AttributeType>String</a:AttributeType>
          <a:Value>Bennelong Point, Sydney NSW 2000, Australia</a:Value>
        </a:EntityMemberAttribute>
        <a:EntityMemberAttribute>
          <a:AttributeName>Address</a:AttributeName>
          <a:AttributeType>String</a:AttributeType>
          <a:Value>Airport Dr, Sydney NSW 2020, Australia</a:Value>
        </a:EntityMemberAttribute>
        <!--And here are my explicit (constant) values -->
        <a:EntityMemberAttribute>
          <a:AttributeName>AddressType</a:AttributeName>
          <a:AttributeType>String</a:AttributeType>
          <a:Value>FactAddress</a:Value>
        </a:EntityMemberAttribute>
</a:Attributes>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that would be with an Inline XSLT Scripting Functoid.

In your case, the XSLT would be just static XML content containing the hard coded EntityMemberAttribute.

Map the dynamic one as usual, then connect the Scripting Functoid also to EntityMemberAttribute and you should get both.